# Razor Format Decimal? value in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4.6 application. I try to format a `Decimal?` property to a correct string format.

My property looks like this:

```
public decimal? Amount{ get; set; }
```

The data from the database looks like this: *10000,99*

My desired outpout should actually be: **€ 10.001**

**no decimal values and no , (comma) is allowed.**

In my Razor view I currently use:

```
@String.Format("{0:N0}", Model.Amount)
```

This works almost fine, though I get this result: **€ 10 000** which is wrong unfortunately.

Do you know hot to solve this in ASP.NET MVC Razor? Desired output € 10.001

Thank you!!!!

Comment: hm, sorry I just don't get it :/ where and how should i put the desired format? thanks

Comment: Sorry for the short comment, i posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Format()` has an overload which accepts `IFormatProvider`. Simply pass the desired number format there:

```
var c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(""); // create InvariantCulture
c.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

var s = String.Format(c, "{0:N0}", 10000.99);
```